# Failed to execute goal on project oozie-sharelib-oozie

Tags: maven, hadoop, oozie

i am trying to configure oozie-4.0.1, with hadoop-2.2.0 and JDK-1.7 in ubuntu 13.10, but getting following error even after changing versions of hadoop in following three files:

```
oozie_home/hadooplibs/hadoop-2/pom.xml
oozie_home/hadooplibs/hadoop-distcp-2/pom.xml
oozie_home/hadooplibs/hadoop-test-2/pom.xml
oozie_home/pom.xml
```

**Error:**

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 2:03.925s
[INFO] Finished at: Mon Feb 09 23:38:56 IST 2015
[INFO] Final Memory: 34M/281M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project oozie-sharelib-oozie: Could not resolve dependencies for project org.apache.oozie:oozie-sharelib-oozie:jar:4.0.1: The following artifacts could not be resolved: org.apache.oozie:oozie-hadoop:jar:2.2.0.oozie-4.0.1, org.apache.oozie:oozie-hadoop-test:jar:2.2.0.oozie-4.0.1: Failure to find org.apache.oozie:oozie-hadoop:jar:2.2.0.oozie-4.0.1 in http://repo1.maven.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/DependencyResolutionException
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command
[ERROR]   mvn <goals> -rf :oozie-sharelib-oozie

ERROR, Oozie distro creation failed
```

i am following this link:http://gauravkohli.com/2014/08/26/apache-oozie-installation-on-hadoop-2-4-1/. Any one pls help here.

Comment: If it helps, I can't find a reference to it on https://maven-repository.com/artifact/org.apache.oozie. Maybe you could paste the relevant bits of your POM?

Answer (score 0):

I faced the said issue coz of Maven was not able to access full internet access, later which was resolve after updating the resolve.conf file with NameServer IP.